# Use a python list in a Socrata Request

Tags: python, socrata

I have connected to a public dataset using Socrata.
As this dataset is very large, I would like to use a where statement in the `.get` statement to filter out certain records.

I only want to import records for which I have matching records in my SQL database. I have created a Python list of these Id's.

I would like to run something like below, but this syntax is invalid.

```
result = client.get(socrata_dataset_id , where ='id in id_list')
```

Is it possible to use a python `list` to as a filter in the `client.get` statement or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If your API endpoint has parameters, you can specify them. Alternatively if the API uses GraphQL you can send a query using the `json` parameter. However, if neither of these are used I'm not sure how you can add a filter that isn't supported by the endpoint.

Comment: This `.get()` function is from which module? Can't you use a `for` loop to iterate over your list?

Comment: hi @Avinash, the client.get() belongs to the Socrata module (https://github.com/xmunoz/sodapy/blob/master/examples/soql_queries.ipynb).  This works: result = client.get(socrata_dataset_id , where ="id in  ('1', '2', '3)")  . Instead of 1,2,3 I have a list of >14.000 records. How would you incorporate a for loop here? I don't want to make 14000 calls to the API

Comment: @MB, the API endpoint does suport filtering, but I'm not sure how I could make i filter based on a list without having to hardcode the items in the call.

Comment: You can loop on the list of ints and escape quotes to contruct the where string.

Comment: @RohitP, wouldnt that result in a large number of API calls?

Comment: Try this: `where ="id in {}".format(id_list)`. But make sure your `id_list` has string values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where` expects a string. You could do something like below, it's not very optimized but you get the idea.

```py
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
ids_str = "id in ("
for i in ids:
    ids_str += f"\'{str(i)}\',"
ids_str = ids_str[:-1]
ids_str += ")"
print(ids_str)

result = client.get(socrata_dataset_id , where = ids_str)
```

Prints

`id in ('1','2','3','4')`